# Install ubuntu 11.10 from 11.04

Tags: 11.04, installation, 11.10

I just tried to install ubuntu 11.10 (from 11.04). All the packages have been downloaded, and installed. But in the end (before cleaning up), a window popped up: `Could not install the upgrades: The upgrade has aborted. Your system could be in an unusable state. A recovery will run now ...`. Then the installation has exit. I manually restarted the computer, visually I am using now ubuntu 11.10. But still the resting stages of installation `cleanning up` has not been run.

Does anyone know if it is normal? What should I do to amend that?

Thank you!

Comment: what happens if you run `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` ?

Comment: Here is the result [http://paste.ubuntu.com/710232/](http://paste.ubuntu.com/710232/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your pastebin trace it looks like you have readded a pidgin PPA.  There is no oneiric version of this PPA - so my advice is to open your software sources and untick this PPA.

i.e.

Open the Dash (click the top icon in the launcher) and search for "software"

[image]

Then find the pidgin PPA and untick it in this tab:

[image]

The rest of the trace shows that you have successfully upgraded to oneiric.

Rerun

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Ensure you have no further errors.  Then you can cleanup outstanding packages that you no longer need and is just taking up disk-space.

```
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Comment: Thank you... `so my advice is to open your software sources and untick this PPA`, could you please tell me more how to do that?

Comment: @softtimur - expanded my answer - hope this helps.